# kubelet was unhealthy after install k8s from Rancher catalog

Tags: kubernetes, catalog, rancher, kubernetes-health-check, kubelet

Have three hosts to run Rancher cluster.

- Rancher: 1.6.10
- Kubernetes: 1.7.7

Install k8s from catalog on master host.

Set `orchestration=true` and `etcd=true` labels to two Rancher agent hosts.

After the k8s stack finished, only the `kubelet` went wrong. `Unhealthy` with 0 containers.

Why?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you check what does "journalctl -xeu kubelet" say ?

Comment: @SureshVishnoi When I run your command on k8s hosts, got `-- No entries --` message.

Comment: It seems to me Kubelet is not installed on the host then.

Comment: I reinstalled k8s cluster and didn't set provider to `aws`. And, didn't set labels to k8s cluster hosts. It works. But it noticed me it's better to set labels such as `etcd=true` in production environment.

Comment: I understand what you mean. However, Could you check if follwing command "systemctl status kubelet" would show the status? Kubelet should be running

Comment: Yes, now it's running.

Comment: Great :) Could we close the question now. I do not know how does it work on StackOverflow when you get your answer how it's accepted.

Comment: @SureshVishnoi You can post an answer below then I will accept it. Thank you very much for your response:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been debugged in the comment section.

**Kubernetes Mantra**

I have added some additional point to keep it in mind to debug the Kubelet.

The K8s cluster is made of Masters and Workers Node which has several components. Kubelet is one the component which needs to take care properly.

Let's begin by saying that Master node manages or orchestrate the cluster state and Workers node run the pods.However, Without Kubelet It does not work Since It will be part of each node whether it's a Master or Worker.
Performance of the cluster certainly depends on the kubelet.

We can use the following command to check its status and activity or logs.As It is deployed as system-service by systemd.

```
systemctl status kubelet
journalctl -xeu kubele
```

Comment: your welcome :) I am glad my insights are helping you. Nonetheless, I am learning more from your questions.